# How Can I get Cell Values from Telerik RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am having a problem getting the values from the Radgrid auto generated Insert form.

I have my radgrid setup as shown in code shown below.  I am only doing inserts and deletes and am using the edit form that is automatically opened when I click the add new record button.

```
    <div id ="specialrequestGrid" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <telerik:RadAjaxPanel runat="server">
                <telerik:RadGrid ID="SpecialRequests" runat="server" OnInsertCommand="SpecialRequests_InsertCommand"
                     OnUpdateCommand="SpecialRequests_UpdateCommand"
                     OnItemCommand="SpecialRequests_ItemCommand"
                     AllowAutomaticInserts="false"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                     OnNeedDataSource="SpecialRequests_NeedDataSource">
                    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="CaseId_FK, ReqId" Font-Size="Medium" NoMasterRecordsText="No Special Requests">
                        <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordImageUrl="../Images/Add.png" />
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Request Date" UniqueName="DateTemplateColumn">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="DateEditItemTemplate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="dpRideDate" runat="server" DateInput-DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" DbSelectedDate='<%# Bind("Date") %>' MinDate="1999/1/1" UniqueName="dpRideDate">
                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Requested By ID" UniqueName="RequestorTemplateColumn">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Requestor" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "RequesterEID_FK") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <button id="btnRequestEID" type="button" class="btn"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >--Please Select--</button>
                                        <div>
                                        <input type="text" Id="TxtSPRequestName" disabled  />
                                    </div>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Request Reason" UniqueName="RequestReason">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="ItemTemplatelblRequestReason" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reason") %>'>
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRequestReason" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reason") %>' Visible="false">
                                        </asp:Label>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtReason" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Reason") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="IsWOO" HeaderText="Is Out of Order" UniqueName="ISWOO"></telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>

            </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the screenshot of the auto generated form I get when I click the add new record

[image: Telerik Generated Inset form]

When I click the Insert link on the form I run this C# code

```
protected void SpecialRequests_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);

        T_SpecialRequests t = new T_SpecialRequests();
        t.IsWOO = (userControl.FindControl("IsWOO") as CheckBox).Checked;
    }
```

Note the IsWOO is a control in the Radgrid that I did not show in the Screenshot.  When I click the save link the Insert Function, shown above Runs but I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at line 1, column 123034 in http://localhost:52028/bundles/MsAjaxJs?v=c42ygB2U07n37m_Sfa8ZbLGVu4Rr2gsBo7MvUEnJeZ81

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The strange part is I use this same code in several other projects without any problems.  The only difference is this is the first time I have used this auto generated form. I don't want to use the another type of control for this Radgrid due to such a small number of fields, only have 4 control.

I have spent several hours searching for an answer but just can't find the solution.

How can I get the values from this auto generated form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Michal Nawrocik was correct I found that I still had some problems reading all of the controls in the Radgrid.  I was able to track down the answer on the Telerik forum and found that you have to use different code based on the Column Type.  I had 2 different type of columns.

the code below shows what I used to get all of the control values on the form

```
protected void SpecialRequests_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
         using(LatentEntities db = new LatentEntities())
            {
                if (e.Item is GridEditableItem)
                {
                    T_SpecialRequests T = new T_SpecialRequests();
                    var editableItem = ((GridEditableItem)e.Item);
                    RadDatePicker picker = (RadDatePicker)editableItem.FindControl("dpDate"); // in EditItem Template
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(picker.DbSelectedDate);
                    T.Date = dt;
                    TextBox Reason = (TextBox)editableItem.FindControl("txtReason"); //This Control was in an Edit Item Template
                    T.Reason = Reason.Text;
                    T.IsWOO = (editableItem["ISWOO"].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked; //In CheckBox Column 


                }
            }
```

And if the control is in a Telerik:GridtboundColumn I used this code:

```
string strFirstName = (editableItem["firstname"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
t.IsWOO = (editedItem["ISWOO"].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked;
```

or

```
var newValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
e.Item.OwnerTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem(newValues, editedItem);
t.IsWOO = (bool)newValues["IsWOO"];
```

The first approach references the control by index because unfortunately it has no ID.

The second one is a bit verbose for just one property but I would surely prefer it if there were more properties.

Comment: The second option is a great answer I can use it in other projects as well.